# Expected state to match memoized state before componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, meteor, react-dom

Upgrading `meteor` (from 1.4 to 1.7) and `react` (from 15.3.2 to 16.8.6) and got this warning at browser console:

```
Warning: Expected Container(Container(withRouter(List))) state to match memoized state before componentDidMount. This might either be because of a bug in React, or because a component reassigns its own `this.props`. Please file an issue.
    in Container(Container(withRouter(List))) (created by UseDeps(Container(Container(withRouter(List)))))
    in UseDeps(Container(Container(withRouter(List)))) (created by RouterContext)
    in div (created by Layout)
    in div (created by Content)
    in Content (created by Layout)
    in div (created by Layout)
    in div (created by Layout)
    in MDLComponent (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by WithDeps(Layout))
    in WithDeps(Layout) (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router
    in Provider
    in Unknown
```

Note: My codes ain't using `react-css-modules` or having `this.props = ...` syntax as suggested in https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14224

Here is my code (which I have narrowed down to, likely at `onPropsChange` part)

**list.js**

```
import {useDeps, composeAll, compose} from 'mantra-core-extra';
import composeWithTracker from '../../core/libs/utils/compose-with-tracker';

import List from '../components/list.jsx';

import Tickets from '../../../../lib/collections';

const composer = ({context}, onData) => {
  const {Meteor, Store} = context();
  if (Meteor.subscribe('tickets').ready()) {
    let filters = Object.assign({}, Store.getState().tickets.list.filters);
    if (filters.date) {
      filters['createdAt'] = {$gt: filters.date.range.start, $lt: filters.date.range.end};
      delete filters['date'];
    }

    let total = Tickets.find(filters).count();
    const tickets = Tickets.find(filters, {
      sort: {[Store.getState().tickets.list.sort.field]: Store.getState().tickets.list.sort.order ? 1 : -1},
      skip: Store.getState().tickets.list.page * Store.getState().tickets.list.range,
      limit: Store.getState().tickets.list.range,
    }).fetch();
    onData(null, {tickets, total});
  }
};

const onPropsChange = ({context}, onData) => {
  const {Store} = context();
  onData(null, Store.getState().tickets);
  return Store.subscribe(() => {
    onData(null, Store.getState().tickets);
  });
};

const depsMapper = (context, actions) => ({
  select: actions.ticket.select,
  unselect: actions.ticket.unselect,
  remove: actions.ticket.remove,
  changePage: actions.ticket.changePage,
  sortField: actions.ticket.sort,
  changeCategory: actions.ticket.changeCategory,
  changeStatus: actions.ticket.changeStatus,
  changeDate: actions.ticket.changeDate,
  find: actions.ticket.find,
  context: () => context
});

export default composeAll(
  composeWithTracker(composer),
  compose(onPropsChange),
  useDeps(depsMapper)
)(List);
```

Appreciate any advise.

**- EDIT -**

Have narrowed down the problem to:

```
const onPropsChange = ({context}, onData) => {
  const {Store} = context();
  onData(null, Store.getState().payment);
  return Store.subscribe(() => {
    onData(null, Store.getState().payment);
  });
};
```

... particularly the `return Store.subscribe` part.

Comment: Perhaps, any expert here can suggest alternative code to overcome this please?

Comment: Did you find any solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in meteorJS, but I happen to have same problem. It usually happens when you try to change the `state` in react in certain way the react doesn't understand. For instance

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {count: 0};
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        // Notice how I am changing it, 
        // without using `this.setState`
        this.state = {count: 1};
    }

    //....
```

In your case, it seems that the function `onData(null, Store.getState().payment);` somehow changes the `payment` property of the state and hence the warning.

Try to replace the part inside `onData` with `this.setState({ payment: ...})` if any update is required.

Comment: Yup, this error is thrown when attempting to change state on a React component directly (`this.state = ...` vs `this.setState(...)`)

Comment: I stumbled on this because I mistakenly put my state initialization in `componentDidMount` instead of `constructor`.